# IOS show status bar when jump to navigation Controller swift 3

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, statusbar

I linked a navgation controller to my UIviewcontroller as below:

[image]

when I logoin status bar is display:

[image]

when I from another viewcontroller return to jump to navigation controller use method as below:

```
let loginPageController=self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "navLoginController") as! UINavigationController

UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .default
self.present(loginPageController, animated:true, completion: nil)
```

the status bar disappeared.

[image]

Anyone can solve it?

Comment: try `override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {return false}`

Answer (score 0):

1- Add this line in appDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function.

```
application.isStatusBarHidden = false
```

2- And in info.plist file add this key.
View controller-based status bar appearance -> YES

Statusbar never hides

Comment: i did it as you said, but status bar still no display

Comment: Then check either you have add  this  override method in your controller class "override func prefersStatusBarHidden()"